# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Android Studio error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ant

Android Studio constantly shows this error message when I try to build:

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:someDummyAppxx'. > taskdef class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp cannot be found  using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

This is what I have:
Studio 2.3.3
Gradle: 2.1.0

Comment: I am not aware of `scp` being a normal part of a build. Are you using any other Gradle plugins (besides the Android one) or any annotation processors?

Comment: yes, I used a third-party plugin, you think the error is from that plugin and not from regular Gladle?